# Trying to connect to Oracle Always Free database using cx_Oracle

Tags: python, database, oracle, cloud, cx-oracle

I have an Always Free Anonymous Database from Oracle and I'm trying to connect to it in Python using cx_Oracle.

Here is my code:

```
import cx_Oracle as cx

#getting the instant client
currentpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
clientpath = os.path.join(currentpath, "instantclient_19_11")
cx.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=clientpath)
#easy connect string
connect_string = "tcps://adb.uk-london-1.oraclecloud.com/t3ulea4zs7iolax_db202008251748_high.atp.oraclecloud.com?wallet_location=/Users/georg/Downloads/Wallet&retry_count=20&retry_delay=3"
userpwd = "(my password)"

def dbConnect():
    con = cx.connect("ADMIN", userpwd, connect_string, encoding="UTF-8")
    print("connection successful")
    return con

con = dbConnect()
```

The error message I get is:
`cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12506: TNS:listener rejected connection based on service ACL filtering`

This is confusing to me as my database is set to allow secure access from anywhere:

"Access Type:
Allow secure access from everywhere"

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. If any more information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: You need to set `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable to the location of your wallet files, then use general TNS entry on connection. I've used it this way: `db.connect(os.environ["ora_cloud_usr"], os.environ["ora_cloud_pwd"], "test_low", encoding="UTF-8" )`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply - I've set my TNS_ADMIN environment variable to my wallet folder and used your code but now I'm getting a KeyError.

Comment: My code uses username and password that are set as environment variables `ora_cloud_usr` and `ora_cloud_pwd` respectively. Just replace them with actual username and password.

Comment: I've tried that, and then I reverted it back to the code I had originally, and now it's working? No idea what I did. Sorry if I wasted your time haha

Comment: You are using the Easy Connect syntax so you don't need to set TNS_ADMIN. What I don't see in your question is the port number in the connection string; was it really the default 1521? For general reference here is a post showing how to create an Easy Connect string for Oracle ABD connections: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/how-connect-to-oracle-autonomous-cloud-databases and here is the cx_Oracle doc on cloud connections https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connecting-to-oracle-cloud-autononmous-databases

Answer (score 0):

To give detail from my comment: If your tnsnames.ora file contains entries like:

```
cjjson_high = (description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)(host=adb.ap-sydney-1.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=abc_cjjson_high.adb.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_cert_dn="CN=adb.ap-sydney-1.oraclecloud.com,OU=Oracle ADB SYDNEY,O=Oracle Corporation,L=Redwood City,ST=California,C=US")))
```

then you can connect using

```
connect_string, = 'tcps://adb.ap-sydney-1.oraclecloud.com:1522/abc_cjjson_high.adb.oraclecloud.com?wallet_location=/Users/cjones/Cloud/CJJSON&retry_count=20&retry_delay=3'
con = cx_Oracle.connect("ADMIN", userpwd, connect_string)
```

With this syntax, you only need the cwallet.sso file from the downloaded cloud wallet.  You don't need tnsnames.ora or sqlnet.ora files. Also you don't need to set TNS_ADMIN.  You just need to change `/Users/cjones/Cloud/CJJSON` in the connect string to the directory containing your cwallet.sso

See the blog post [How to connect to Oracle Autonomous Cloud Databases](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/how-connect-to-oracle-autonomous-cloud-databases) which gives information about getting the wallet and the cx_Oracle documentation [Connecting to Oracle Cloud Autononmous Databases](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connecting-to-oracle-cloud-autononmous-databases).

Footnote: the `encoding` parameter defaults to UTF-8 in cx_Oracle 8 onwards.